# Case last modified date doesn't match actual last modified date?

Tags: case

I'm trying to make a View of cases that haven't been interacted with in a while. I sorted by Last Modified Date, but it looks like a lot of the cases have been receiving notes added, etc. much later than the Last Modified Date. Is there some manner in which I can check the true last date that anything in the case was updated or touched? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Comments and related record creation doesn't cause an 'update' on the case, so that's why your last modified date isn't reflecting those interactions.  The two options I see would be to either add the appropriate related list to the report and filter against the related record values, or to add a WFR or Trigger to update a new field on the case anytime the appropriate related item is added.  The second option doesn't help you **now**, but will in the future.